# PHP remove whitespace only if string contain whitespace only

Tags: php

I am using bootstrap-wysiwyg.min.js for editor to edit the content and its working fine. Now I need to remove whitespace only if the textarea editor contains whitespace.

I have tried `trim` but is not enough because before inserting into database I use:

```
htmlentities($request->student_registration_msg);
```

to convert it to html.

is there a way to remove `&nbsp;` only if it contain only whitespace

```
 <?php

  $str="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp";
$acs=preg_replace('/^(\&nbsp;|<br>|\s)+$/i', '', $str);
$demo=html_entity_decode($str);

echo htmlentities($acs);

    ?>
```

Comment: In php or javascript? Show your code where you are trying to remove the spaces

Comment: i am trying to it in php after submitting form.even jquery is fine

Comment: Are you trying to remove spaces i.e. `' ' ` or `&nbsp;`

Comment: &nbsp; only if it contain only &nbsp; or else ok

Comment: DId you try to use RegExp?

Comment: Did you tried strip_tags instead of htmlentities ?

Comment: @NastasiaMirolubova. i dont know how to write regular exprerssion for this

Comment: Try : trim(strip_tags($request->student_registration_msg))

Comment: have you try `str_replace` ?

Comment: @Muthu17 `strip_tags()` is not going to test if the string contains ONLY `&nbsp;`

Comment: "/^(&nbsp;)*$/"  - if a string contains only whitespaces

Comment: @RiggsFolly.you are right.i need to trim only after html entities because i am storing html content

Comment: @NastasiaMirolubova. $d=preg_match("/^(&nbsp;)*$/",htmlentities($request->student_registration_msg));
          print_r($d); always return 0

Comment: Try this $d=preg_match("/(&nbsp;)*/",htmlentities($request->student‌​_registration_msg));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove the whitespace **AFTER** you save your data and process it with `htmlentities`. (Seems weird that you'd do it this way, but you provided very little code to go on.

In any case, it could be easily solved with a call to `preg_replace`:

```
preg_replace('/^(\&nbsp;|\s)+$/i', '', $data)
```

Which means: replace all whitespace characters or non-braking whitespace html entities if the string only contains instances of those characters.

You can see a working example [here](https://repl.it/GWRT/0).

Comment: @yivi.now i have another problem where sometimes $str="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; string contain <br> in between or at the end in that case how we can write preg match .i tried '/^(\&nbsp;|<br>|\s)+$/i' this will work only if <br> at the end not in between

Comment: Should work. but you have some extra `;` in that string, just after one of the <br>s, which is breaking the regexp. ";" by itself a whitespace character is not.

Comment: @iCoders Again, it's because you have a `;` where it doesn't belong. Why do you have  `<br>;`? (check for the extra semi-colon after the second  <br> tag).

Comment: ya ur right.that i removed already still not working.any way.thanks .i will try if its working i will post it .thanks a lot

Comment: @yivi.thanks you are right its working in online editor not in xamp may be version issue.

Comment: extremely doubtful. something else is amiss in your code.

Comment: @yivi.yes .its not working in online editor for above condtion .i have updated question

Comment: Your **last** `&nbsp;` doesn't end in a semi-colon. Again, your input is wrong. https://repl.it/GWRT/4

Comment: @yivi.extremly sorry .i have made bullshit mistake.thanks for notfiying thanks a lot for taking time for me to solve.may god bless you